# Docker / PHP / Apache - File permissions lost when created inside container

Tags: php, apache, docker, symfony

i'm trying to set up a docker app with Apache and Php stack.
But when i create a new file inside my project container, the permissions losted because root user is connected by default.
How can I connect my host user ?

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: docker/web
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/var/www/app
      - ./docker/web/apache/log:/var/log/apache2/app
    working_dir: /var/www/app
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        git \
        zip \
        unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip pdo pdo_mysql opcache \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN rm /etc/localtime
RUN ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris /etc/localtime
RUN "date"


RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

COPY php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/app.ini
COPY apache/app.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN groupadd dev -g 1000
RUN useradd dev -g dev -d /home/dev -m
RUN echo '%dev ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
```

I tried to create a dev user in my Dockerfile but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding my dev user to sudoers and then running apache2ctl in sudo.

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        sudo \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        git \
        zip \
        unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip pdo pdo_mysql opcache \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN rm /etc/localtime
RUN ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris /etc/localtime
RUN "date"


RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!/var/www!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!/var/www!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

COPY php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/app.ini
COPY apache/app.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN groupadd dev -g 1000
RUN useradd dev -g dev -d /home/dev -m
RUN echo '%dev ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
USER dev:dev

CMD ["sudo", "/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Answer (score 1):

And how about this?

```
# Add www-data to the '1000-group'
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
```

Comment: Actually, it's working when i'm connecting to container with `docker exec -it -u dev:dev web bash` but i want to automatically connect with dev user when connecting with `docker exec -it web bash`

Comment: When adding `USER dev:dev` in my dockerfile, i have "Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down"